# Rendering fonts from flash to image

Tags: php, flash, fonts, rendering, imagemagick

I am trying to render an image with text and images that are on a .swf file. What i am doing is saving all the objects and their properties in an XML and then using  imagemagick to render all that. the problem i am facing is that imagemagick treats fonts very different than Flash, so i don't get a perfect copy of what i see in the flash to what i see on the rendered image.

Can anyone share some light on how to match font sizes between flash an imagemagick? I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: What sizes are you using right now in Flash and IM, respectively?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to save some image that you can see on the flash movie to a file? If so you can use Jpeg encoder in flash to do exactly that. Here is an example: http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/

You still need a php or some other technology to post the data to and save it as a file so that the user can download it.

Comment: Did you take a look at this? I think its what you want.

Comment: @asheinfeld, if this solved your problem then please accept the right answer :)